# Mac - git svn error - Can't load '/usr/X/X/subversion/lib/perl5/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/SVN/XXX/_Core.bundle' for module SVN::_Core: dlo

Tags: git, macos, version-control, macos-monterey

Terminal - git svn getting below errors and can't take a git svn clone in any svn repository.

```
Can't load '/usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.bundle' for module SVN::_Core: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN/_Core/_Core.bundle, 0x0001): Symbol not found: _apr_crypto_block_cleanup
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.14.1_4/lib/libsvn_subr-1.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib at /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 197.
 at /usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN/Base.pm line 59.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN/Core.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/opt/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/opt/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/opt/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/opt/git/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/bin/git-svn line 23.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/git-svn line 23.
```

Comment: git-svn is written partly in Perl, so you need to get perl working correctly to run it. Why perl is failing, I don't know, beyond the obvious (the missing symbol).

Comment: There is no any error in perl if I run perl --version then getting below response


This is perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level

Copyright 1987-2021, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

Comment: That's because perl has dynamic linking. Until you try to access whatever perl *module* has the missing symbol, everything is fine. Find out which module this is (it's right there in the error output) and dig in to that.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error messages on my Mac. I found a solution that solved the problem for me [here](https://github.com/afragen/setup-phpunit/issues/5).

Quick answer: Reinstall *apr-util* via

```
brew reinstall apr-util
```